# Pycharm can‘t find and list packages in conda's virtual environment which I creat

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

It can't list the packages what I have installed in DLenv

[image: python interpreter]

and if I switch interpreter from base to this venv, after a long time of loading packages list, This error message has displayed.

[image: error massage]
the chinese in error corrected means that "the system can't find the specified path"

and the error massage is as follow:
“Error while loading conda entry point: conda-build ((-2147024893, '系统找不到指定的路径。', None, None))
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 17, in **call**
return func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 57, in main_subshell
context.**init**(argparse_args=args)
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 459, in **init**
CONDA_PREFIX=determine_target_prefix(self, argparse_args),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1975, in determine_target_prefix
return validate_prefix_name(prefix_name, ctx=ctx)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1935, in validate_prefix_name
return locate_prefix_by_name(prefix_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1894, in locate_prefix_by_name
envs_dirs = context.envs_dirs
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 657, in envs_dirs
return mockable_context_envs_dirs(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 125, in mockable_context_envs_dirs
fixed_dirs.append(join(user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME), "envs"))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\appdirs.py", line 266, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
dir = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, getattr(shellcon, csidl_name), 0, 0)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024893, '系统找不到指定的路径。', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 166, in print_unexpected_error_report
get_main_info_str(error_report["conda_info"])
File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 254, in get_main_info_str
info_dict[f"_{key}"] = ("\n" + 26 * " ").join(map(str, info_dict[key]))
~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 57, in main_subshell
    context.__init__(argparse_args=args)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 459, in __init__
    CONDA_PREFIX=determine_target_prefix(self, argparse_args),
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1975, in determine_target_prefix
    return validate_prefix_name(prefix_name, ctx=ctx)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1935, in validate_prefix_name
    return locate_prefix_by_name(prefix_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1894, in locate_prefix_by_name
    envs_dirs = context.envs_dirs
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 657, in envs_dirs
    return mockable_context_envs_dirs(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 125, in mockable_context_envs_dirs
    fixed_dirs.append(join(user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME), "envs"))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
    path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 266, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
    dir = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, getattr(shellcon, csidl_name), 0, 0)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024893, '系统找不到指定的路径。', None, None)
```

`$ D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py list -n DLenv`

environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install "

and I can run conda list from my command prompt and the packages can be listed successfully.
[conda list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb47M.png)

thank for your answer, it's my first time to use stackoverflow,so if there is anything wrong, please forgive me :(

try:

1. I have check whether the path related to CONDA and pychar has been added to the environment variable and restart computer,but it didn't work
2. I try to manually add packages one by one in pycharm, but I give up fastly beacuse Because I found that this kind of the efficiency is too low

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages. Copy/paste their content into the body of your question

Comment: Can you run `conda list` from your command prompt (outside of Pycharm) succesfully?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)